# How do I specify a lower gas price in the Ethereum Wallet when creating a wallet contract?

Tags: wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp, gas-price

I'm trying out the [Ethereum Wallet Dapp](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases) (which may or may not also be called Mist, I'm a little confused about the naming. But the About screen says "Ethereum Wallet 0.8.10").

This wallet app seems to be geared towards using a "wallet contract", required to display transaction history. When I try to create one the wallet suggests a gas price which would amount to about $14 (0.02265 ether per million gas, expecting to use 2M gas). That feels like quite a lot for what it is.

Checking http://ethgasstation.info it seems clear that a much lower gas price would work. I'm fine with creation running more slowly.

How do I set a lower gas price in the Ethereum Wallet?